# Android HttpURLConnection not setting headers

Tags: android

I set headers on a HTTP URL connection on Android, but they're not being sent or set!

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Date", "Now");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "All");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Test-Header", "Where");
activity.LogTextToScreen( "Request: " + urlConnection.getRequestMethod());
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
    activity.LogTextToScreen( "" + urlConnection.getHeaderFieldKey(i) + "=" + urlConnection.getHeaderField(i));
}
```

```
Request: GET
Cache-Control=max-age=600
Content-Length=1662
Content-Type=application/json
Etag="27f857efb34b2639673ae3e866c5d901d4d9ebbf2a1684b0d7d8e110c68c1881"
Expires=Mon, 14 Nov 2022 20:01:20 UTC
Last-Modified=Fri, 11 Nov 2022 20:11:25 GMT
Permissions-Policy=interest-cohort=()
Vary=Origin
Date=Mon, 14 Nov 2022 19:51:20 GMT
X-Android-Sent-Millis=1668455479654
X-Android-Received-Millis=1668455479974
X-Android-Selected-Protocol=http/1.1
X-Android-Response-Source=NETWORK 200
null=null
null=null
null=null
null=null
```

Android 12.

Setting it in many different ways!

Comment: You might be happier with a more modern HTTP client API, such as OkHttp.

Comment: Thanks, just tried OKHttp, works fine. Sets the header, does the download.

Is this a bug in the default Android 12 HttpURLConnection, that it just doesn't allow setting any headers?? That's crazy if so.

Comment: Well, you are logging response headers from the looks of it. I have no idea if HttpUrlConnection supports reading back your request headers.

Comment: Oh, I see! Well it still doesn't download the file.

Is there a way to log what HttpURLConnection actually sends to the web server? That would be REALLY handy!

Comment: If you have an older device or emulator (Android 8.1 or lower), you can use Charles Proxy to inspect Web traffic. Beyond that, I don't have a lot of advice, as I have not used HttpUrlConnection in years.